# Read/save image from/to file in R

Tags: r, image, file, io

I need to read an image from a file, do some basic operations pixel-wise and then be able to save it to a file.

I read about the `png` library and other similar ones, but they don't seem to let you save an image to a file.

My images are currently in GIF format but I wouldn't mind having to convert them to any other conventional format.

Do you know any useful package for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PNG library should allow you to save a file no problems.

See `?png::writePNG` which will...

> "Create a PNG image from an array or matrix."

...and which includes the `target=` argument...

> target: Either **name of the file to write**, a binary connection or a
>             raw vector (‘raw()’ - the default - is good enough)
>             indicating that the output should be a raw vector.